# The span of the image of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ and $GL(V)$ in ${\rm End}(V^{\otimes n})$ are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm studying the theorem $4.2$ in this PDF [Schur-Weyl duality](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/Finite%20Group%20Rep%20Theory7.pdf).

I can understand that if $X \in{\rm End}(V)$ then $X$ is in span of $\lbrace g : g \in GL(V) \rbrace$.

To finish the proof I need to prove that $X^{\otimes n}$ is in span of $\lbrace g^{\otimes n}: g \in GL(V) \rbrace$.

Somone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think they are the same, just that they span the same vector subspace.

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong! Thank you

Comment: Is $V$ a vector space over an infinite field?

Comment: @darijgrinberg You can consider $V$ over complex